# Python (manimgl) cannot find module in current directory

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, manim

I'm trying to run a python program (specifically, I'm running manimgl, but I don't think that matters here) and the first line reads `from manim_imports_ext import *`.  However, I am getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'manim_imports_ext'` even though I have verified that the file `manim_imports_ext.py` is in the current working directory.  The program itself is in a subdirectory, but that doesn't seem relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated; it seems like I must be doing something dumb.

Comment: Have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder), you might find the solution you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The question does seem quite similar, but I was not able to figure out a solution for my situation.